# Group data by part of string in oracle sql ( Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, oracle9i

I have the following query:

```
select referrer, count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
       sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
       sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from advert_view_hits
where ad_id in ({$id_strings})
group by referrer"
```

This will return data like the following:

```
 Referrer  Adverts  Clicks  Views
 Caterer     3       124     74
 Indeed      5       234     136
```

Which is fine but some cases the referrer has been stored in the db like this:

```
user1@jwrecruitment.co.uk_200890,
user2@jwrecruitment.co.uk_200890

user1@gatewayjobs.co.uk_200890, 
user3@towngate-personnel.co.uk_2
```

How would I go about grouping the data based on just the company of the user emails that have been used as the referrer.

so the data would look like this:

```
Referrer             Adverts  Clicks  Views
 Caterer               3       124     74
 Indeed                5       234     136
 jwrecruitment.co.uk   8       456     782 
 gatewayjobs.co.uk     9       897     959
```

So that all data for an emails like jwrecruitment.co.uk would be grouped together and displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `regexp_substr` to find the string between `@` and `_` as follows:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(referrer,'@([^_]+)',1,1,NULL,1) referrer, 
       count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
       sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
       sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
  from advert_view_hits
where ad_id in ({$id_strings})
group by REGEXP_SUBSTR(referrer,'@([^_]+)',1,1,NULL,1)
```

If you are on older version then instead of regexp_substr use the combination of the SUBSTR and INSTR as follows:

```
SUBSTR(referrer, 
       INSTR(referrer, '@') + 1, 
       DECODE(INSTR(referrer, '_', - 1), 
              0, 
              LENGTH(referrer) - INSTR(referrer, '@'), 
              INSTR(referrer, '_', - 1) - INSTR(referrer, '@') - 1)
      )
```

Comment: Says ORA-00904: "REGEXP_SUBSTR": invalid identifier. Highlighting the group_by clause

Comment: I should add this is an older version of oracle

Comment: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you could use `regexp_replace()` :

```
select 
    regexp_replace(referrer, '^.*@([^_]+).*$', '\1') referrer, 
    count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
    sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
    sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from advert_view_hits
where ad_id in ({$id_strings})
group by regexp_replace(referrer, '^.*@([^_]+).*$', '\1')
```

The regexp matches on referrer that contain a arobas, and captures the part after the arobas and before the next underscore. If the referrer does not match the regex, it is left untouched.

Comment: ORA-00904: "REGEXP_REPLACE": invalid identifier on the group_by

Comment: this is  Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0 and doesn't have that function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can take everything after the `@` -- and you can do that using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(referrer, '[^@]+$') as referrer, count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
       sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
       sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from advert_view_hits
where ad_id in ({$id_strings})
group by regexp_substr(referrer, '[^@]+$') ;
```

You can replace the `regexp_substr()` logic with:

```
select substr(referrer, instr(referrer, '@') + 1) as referrer, count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
       sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
       sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from advert_view_hits
where ad_id in ({$id_strings})
group by  substr(referrer, instr(referrer, '@') + 1) ;
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "REGEXP_SUBSTR": invalid identifier. Highlighting the group_by clause. I should add this is an older version of oracle

Comment: @user794846 . . . `regexp_substr()` is definitely part of Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) and has been for a long, long time.  That suggests some other issue in the query -- perhaps a problem in the `where` clause.

Comment: this is a legacy system running on Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production